# Unable to get $(window).scrollTop() javascript to work

Tags: javascript, css, scrolltop

I'm trying to implement a javascript solution to hide floating share buttons and only have them appear when a user scrolls below 830px.

Expected behaviour - shareaholic share buttons hidden until user scrolls 830px. Buttons should appear at that point. The code that I have used is:

```
.shareaholic-share-buttons-container.floated.vertical {
display: none;
}
```

the above is in my CSS followed by:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).scroll(function() {
if ($(window).scrollTop() > 830) {
$('.shareaholic-share-buttons-container.floated.vertical').show();
} else {
$('.shareaholic-share-buttons-container.floated.vertical').hide();
}

});
</script>
```

I have searched for all the iterations of javascript solution to hiding elements upon scroll and I have tried the following code as well:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).scroll(function() {
if($(window).scrollTop() > 830) {
$(".shareaholic-share-buttons-container.floated.vertical").css("display","block"); 
} else {
$(".shareaholic-share-buttons-container.floated.vertical").css("display","none"); 
}
});
</script>
```

Unfortunately that doesn't work as well. I have placed it at the end of my header and at the end of my footer just before the `</body>` but nothing works.

I would appreciate all help in getting the code to work on my site at http://thehungrygeek.com - thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add jQuery instead of $ sign.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
if(jQuery(window).scrollTop() > 830) {
jQuery(".shareaholic-share-buttons-container.floated.vertical").css("display","block"); 
} else {
jQuery(".shareaholic-share-buttons-container.floated.vertical").css("display","none"); 
}
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Is there something special with my site's script setup that the $ sign had to be replaced with jQuery instead?

Comment: are you using something like wordpress? or a JS library that uses $? jQuery loads in 'safe mode' when that is the case.

Comment: Yes you add like this in your custom js see this link  https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/